# Loop can't see the value's changing from False to True

Tags: function, while-loop

Im trying to launch a loop using function in python. the fucntion changes the False in running variable to True. And the pygame game runs when the running variable is True. But when it changes to True, the loop can't see it.

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
from tkinter import *

pygame.init()

running = False
def starter():

    global running
    running = True
    print(running)

root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text="Run", command=starter)
button.pack()


while running:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

root.mainloop()
```

I tried separating loops with time.sleep() and mentioning running as global